# React-Native Picker cannot initialize a default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a Picker and I have to show my default value on initialization of Picker but selectedValue is not firing at first call.

That is my Picker:

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={this.props.expense.currency}
    onValueChange={(val) => {
        let expenses = [...this.props.expense];
        expenses[index].currency = val;
        this.props.setExpense(expenses);
    }}>

    <Picker.Item label='Select Money' value='default'/>
    {
        loginType.currency.map((i) => {
            return (<Picker.Item label={i.TYPE} value={i}/>)
        })
    }
</Picker>
```

`this.props.expense.currency` returns:

```
{
    CODE: '2',
    TYPE: 'EUR'
}
```

**It has to come with `'EUR'` as default. But it comes with `'Select Money'`.**

It is been a day and I couldn't find any solution. I researched for defaultValue but there is nothing like that on Github pages. Any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use something that is comparable for the picker item value prop.

I am assuming what is happening here is that the object comparison between `this.props.expense.currency` and the `value` prop on each `Picker.Item` is failing so it is defaulting to the first. Try mapping the value to the code rather than the full object, like this:

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={this.props.expense.currency.CODE}
    onValueChange={(val) => {
        let expenses = [...this.props.expense];
        let newVal = loginType.currency.find(item => item.CODE === val)
        expenses[index].currency = newVal;
        this.props.setExpense(expenses);
    }}>

    <Picker.Item label='Select Money' value='default'/>
    {
        loginType.currency.map((i) => {
            return (<Picker.Item label={i.TYPE} value={i.CODE}/>)
        })
    }
</Picker>
```